# Two images on my website are different height to others

Tags: html, css

[two of these images are different height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8K6G.png)

I'm doing a web dev course online and first HTML/CSS section revolves around making a website as you cover each topic. I'm trying to make all these images appear one next to the other and have the same size - for some reason two of the divs still remain larger than the rest, setting height does not work for these two.

Here is what I tried in CSS:

```
body{
font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
background:white;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;

.product {
border: 1px solid grey;
width: 200px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}

img{
max-width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

And example of how all divs from .product class were created:

```
 <div class="product">
<a href="product-details-lip-balm.html">
    <img src="images/makeup5.jpg" alt="Lip balm">
</a>
<h4><a href="product-details-lip-balm.html">Lip balm</a></h4>
<p> &pound; 5</p>
<p> Organic lip balm by Make Me Bio</p>
<a href="product-detail.html" class="button">More info</a>
<a href="" class="button">Add To Cart</a>
```

[two images have different height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8K6G.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add your relevant code and maybe a screenshot of the problem you are facing? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56325179/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like the images may be a different height and/or width to the others.  However without more detail, we can't really help.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that, I'll try and be more clear. I just tried setting height for all images on my main page and it kinda "worked" i.e. all images are in line, however two of them still have different height - I'll edit my question to show exactly what I mean.

Comment: The 3 lines of text do the extra height.

Comment: Is there any way to make sure the height stays the same and eg the font size decreases instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think probably you can use "display:block;" instead of "display:inline-block;"

Use following code in the class "product".

```
   .product {
        display: block;
        float:left;   
     }
```

And if you provide "margin:auto;" for the img, then the image will be center.

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
  max-height:200px;
}
```

will work!

Comment: It didn't unfortunately, was the first thing I tried :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to fix this - at that point I didn't know anything about Flexbox but now I just started the second part of this course on Skillshare and apparently putting all of product divs into a flex container and setting flex-wrap: wrap; fixes my problem.  Yay, so happy. Thank you everyone for help!